# Free access to the OED in the Americas (13-19 April 2014)

Tags: discussion

This is more of an announcement than discussion but [this](http://global.oup.com/academic/librarians/national-library-week/?cc=fi&lang=en&) may be useful for people here and [EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/free-access-to-the-oed-in-the-americas-13-19-april-2014):

> **National Library Week**
>
> ***All OUP Online products are free April 13-19th***
>
> To celebrate National Library Week in the United States (April 13th-19th) and all the hard work librarians do to support their patrons, OUP is freeing up all of our online products* for the week! Libraries are a vital part of many communities, whether it is a school, a town/city, the government, a corporation, or a hospital, and we have freed up this unprecedented amount of content to show our appreciation for these libraries.
>
> Simply use the below login credentials!
> No sign-ups are required!
>
> Username: libraryweek
> Password: libraryweek

Comment: Hugo, thank you. I hope I can have free access from Italy, too. +1

Comment: @Carlo_R. Probably you do. Just try it, at least I've heard it working in India, Iran and Finland.

Comment: Updated for 2014!

Comment: Thanks for keeping us updated on this Hugo. Very useful to be reminded of this for 2014.